# Weird translation effect on my cube

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, glm-math

I am trying to support "basic" rotation translation and scaling on an openGL cube.
The code for drawing my cube is the following:

```
void drawCube(){
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);                // Begin drawing the color cube with 6 quads
      // Top face (y = 1.0f)
      // Define vertices in counter-clockwise (CCW) order with normal pointing out
      glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);     // Green
      glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
      glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
      glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f);
      glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f);

      // Bottom face (y = -1.0f)
      glColor3f(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f);     // Orange
      glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);
      glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);
      glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
      glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);

      // Front face  (z = 1.0f)
      glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);     // Red
      glVertex3f( 1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f);
      glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f);
      glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
      glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);

      // Back face (z = -1.0f)
      glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);     // Yellow
      glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
      glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
      glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f);
      glVertex3f( 1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f);

      // Left face (x = -1.0f)
      glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);     // Blue
      glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f);
      glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f);
      glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
      glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);

      // Right face (x = 1.0f)
      glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);     // Magenta
      glVertex3f(1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f);
      glVertex3f(1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f);
      glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);
      glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
   glEnd();  // End of drawing color-cube
} 
    void display(void)
{

    //Angle of view:40 degrees
    //Near clipping plane distance: 0.5
    //Far clipping plane distance: 20.0

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();

    // clear the drawing buffer.
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    // clear the identity matrix.
    glMultMatrixf(rM);
    // scaling transfomation 
    glScalef(0.5,0.5,0.5);
    glPushMatrix();
    drawCube();
    glPopMatrix();

    // Flush buffers to screen
    glFlush(); 
    SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();       
    // sawp buffers called because we are using double buffering 

}
```

I am using glm to create the transformation matrix representing rotation translation and scaling applied. I use the mouse coordinates in order to find the corresponding translation, rotation ... 
The rotation works just fine, however when I'm trying the translation I get weird results. For instance, I can only see the yellow face of the cube and there are no ways of recovering the cube at all. I tried printing the transformation matrix to check whether it was correct or not and it seems corrects.
Here is how I get my transformation matrix

```
rM = translationMatrix * mMatNow * scaleMatrix ;
```

Here is my original transformation matrix:

1    ; 0     ; 0     ; 0     ; 
0    ; 1     ; 0     ; 0     ; 
0    ; 0     ; 1     ; 0     ; 
0    ; 0     ; 0     ; 1     ;

Here is the one after a quick translation:

1    ; 0     ; 0     ; -7    ; 
0    ; 1     ; 0     ; 0     ; 
0    ; 0     ; 1     ; 0     ; 
0    ; 0     ; 0     ; 1     ;

Accordingly here are the corresponding images:
[image: Original Drawing]
[image: After Translation]

Comment: Not sure if that's just an error in copying/typing the matrix into the question, but the first value in the matrix should still be `1` in the second matrix that includes the translation.

Comment: That was indeed an error, thanks for noticing. Edit on the way

Comment: Looks like you should transpose your matrix.

Comment: Why should I ? The rotation seems to be working just fine so I'm guessing the matrix does not need to be transposed otherwise even the rotation would not work

Comment: A translated rotation matrix still results in a rotation matrix, just with the opposite rotation direction, so it might be easy to overlook that.

Comment: @derhass Yet my problem is not with the rotation but with the translation

Comment: Yes. And that's why you should try to transpose those matrices.  A transposed translation will result in a weird perspective effect.

Comment: So do you mean I should transpose the product or each one of them first and then multiply because (AB) transposed is not equal to A transposed * B transposed

Comment: that depens on what excatly you are doing. If the numbers you pronted for the matrix represent the sequence of the elements in memory you are feeding to `glMultMatrix`, the matrices are definitively transposed. The translation part should be in the elements `m[12]`, `m[13]`, `m[14]` by GL's convention. What's weird is that you say you use glm, which normally follows GL's convention, so it is unclear where your matrices get transposed.

Comment: My bad the problem was that I was not calling glMultMatrix with the value returned by glm::value_ptr. You pointed me in the right direction. Therefore I think no transpose is needed